# How do I remove these cracks from my imported svg. file? I'm trying to extrude it

Tags: extrude, svg

I'm new to Blender and I'm trying to import an SVG. artwork from Adobe Illustrator into Blender and then extrude it.

(I'm using Blender 2.83.5 and Adobe illustrator 2020)

I have followed the steps in this video -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQjy4_337wQ&t=4s

But when I extrude my artwork I get lots of little cracks all throughout it.

Is anyone able to tell me why this is? And how I can get rid of them?

Please see my screenshots below.

Thank you to anyone who is willing to help (づ￣ ³￣)づ

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Image of Blender Artwork in 'Edit Mode'
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the mesh in edit mode? I wonder if there are extra edges or faces. Or even better, upload the file here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and update your post with the link

Comment: @JeffLange Thanks for getting back to me and helping me with the screenshot/link suggestion. I've gone an added a screenshot of the mesh in edit mode and uploaded the working file above. Would love to know what you think? I'm very new to this.

Comment: From your last screenshot it looks like Jeff's doubt is confirmed. It seems to have exra faces and missing faces. Could you add a screenshot of the mesh in edit mode before extruding it?
Other question: When you export from Illustrator does it give you options or it just export the mesh without having the possibility to change any setting? Thanks.

Comment: Blender doesn’t know where to connect the faces, so you’ll likely need to manually do that part. I’m not aware of a way to do this an easier way.